# R: how to display 2019-04-29 as 29 of may of 2019 in ggplot subtitle?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to put the min date value and the max date value in `ggplot subtitle`.

I've found a similar question but for the axis labels, I need to apply this to the subtitle argument:

```
subtitle = paste0("Del ", vitocho_likes_min_date, " al ", vitocho_likes_max_date)
```

**Min date looks like**:

```
"2010-10-14" #Expect: "14 de octubre del 2010"

dput(vitocho_likes_min_date)
structure(14896, class = "Date")
```

**Max date looks like**:

```
"2019-04-29" #Expect: "29 de abril del 2019"

dput(vitocho_likes_max_date)
structure(18015, class = "Date")
```

This is my ggplot chart:

```
vitocho_chart <- t_kids_faves %>%
  filter(user == "VictorAndresGB") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(screen_name, n), y = n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "#494A4F") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_tweets() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "",
    title = "Cuentas de Twitter con más likes de Victor Andrés García Belaunde.",
    subtitle = paste0("Del ", vitocho_likes_min_date, " al ", vitocho_likes_max_date)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = screen_name,
        y = n - 15,
        label = n
    ),
    size = 4,
    color = "gray95"
  )
```

Comment: You mean 'April' not 'May'?

Comment: Like that `strftime(vitocho_likes_min_date, "%d of %b, of %Y")`?

Comment: We don't have your data to recreate this, and you haven't shown any output, but does calling `paste0` inside your subtitle not work once you've formatted the date the way you want? I don't see why passing a formatted date to the subtitle would be any different.

Comment: It was just a formating thing, no need for a full data frame here. captoma did hit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish") 
vitocho_likes_min_date= as.character(format(as.Date(14896, origin="1970-01-01"), "%d de %B del %Y"))
vitocho_likes_max_date= as.character(format(as.Date(18015, origin="1970-01-01"), "%d de %B del %Y"))
```

Comment: My label return Del X de **October** del ... Even setting `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")`.

Comment: @OmarGonzales try `Sys.setlocale(locale="es_ES.UTF-8")` or `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Spanish")`